# Sum by Distinct Values

Tags: sql, t-sql, group-by, sum, case

I have the below code which brings though a sum of where a day 'GRLastDt' has complete or not complete however I hadn't accounted for duplicated Return IDs. Is there a way to return a sum by day for each Return ID?

For example day 24/5/15 may have 5 Lines to the day which have 'X' in Complete however 2 lines have duplicated return ids 'RtnId' and therefore the sum total would be 4 rather than 5 for 24/5/15.

```
SELECT  
    CONVERT(varchar(15), GRLastDt, 111) AS Date_,
    SUM(CASE WHEN Complete = 'X' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Complete, 
    SUM(CASE WHEN Complete <> 'X' /*and RtnDt <>GRLastDt*/THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Due
FROM [dbo].[vw_AN_Admin_VendorReturns]
WHERE (GRLastDt >= GETDATE() - 30)   
GROUP BY CONVERT(varchar(15), GRLastDt, 111),GRLastDt
```

Comment: So you want to remove duplicate data ? or add the return Id's to the group by result set ?

Comment: Please edit your question with sample data and desired results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand your problem right I think you can change this line:

```
SUM(CASE WHEN Complete = 'X' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Complete,
```

to this:

```
COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN Complete = 'X' THEN RtnId END) AS Complete,
```

You probably want the same change for the Due calculation.